# Pattern matching within a string

Tags: bash, glob

I am writing a bash script that contained a command similar to:

```
echo Configure with --with-foo=\"/tmp/foo-*\"
```

I wanted this command to produce output such as:

```
Configure with --with-foo="/tmp/foo-1.3.2"
```

but the pattern wasn't expanded because it was embedded within a string.  I got it to work by using command substitution:

```
echo Configure with --with-foo=\"$(echo /tmp/foo-*)\"
```

I think this is the standard /bin/sh solution, but does bash support a solution that doesn't require forking a sub-shell, in the same way that `$((6 * 7))` can be used in place of `$(expr 6 \* 7)`?  Also, is there a way to restrict the result to a single match?

Comment: Perhaps `printf "Configure with --foo=\"%s\"\n" /tmp/foo-*`? Although the whole idea seems a bit fragile, because `/tmp/foo-*` might match nothing, or more than one thing, which might lead to odd issues...

Comment: @twalberg There should be exactly one match if all is well, so I'd actually like to generate an error if there isn't.

Comment: Yeah it's the "if all isn't well" that I was referring to, so you might need some logic before the `printf` to ensure that all is, in fact, well...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To check how many files your pattern expands into, store the expansion into an array before using it

```
shopt -s nullglob
foo=(/tmp/foo-*)
if   (( ${#foo[@]} == 0 )); then echo "no foo files"
elif (( ${#foo[@]}  > 1 )); then echo "too many foo files"
else do something with "${foo[0]}"
fi
```

Answer (score 1):

As alternative, use a `for` loop and `break` after first iteration:

```
shopt -s nullglob
for f in /tmp/foo-*; do 
    echo "Configure with --with-foo=\"$f\""
    break
done
```

Comment: Note that depends on the bash `nullglob` option being set: if it is unset, then f will be `'/tmp/foo-*'` -- add `shopt -s nullglob`